# How to handle loading times when a user clicks a Link or NavLink in remix run

Tags: reactjs, remix, remix.run

I am building an app with remix run and using nested components.
When you click a NavLink or Link that loads a component that has a loader function to load data from an api, it can be very slow to get the response and render to the user.
Ideally I would like the URL in the browser to change immediately on click and to load an animation while the component is loading.
I know how I could implement the loading animation with react and the useEffect hook, however I'm not sure how you'd do this with remix and the Link/NavLink tags.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remix tries to emulate the browser behaviour when navigating, so it doesn't change the URL until the loader has resolved.

However, you can improve the UX by showing some loading UI with `useNavigation`.

```js
export default function App() {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <Meta />
        <Links />
      </head>
      <body>
        {navigation.state !== "idle" ? <div>Loading...</div> : null}
        <Outlet />
        <ScrollRestoration />
        <Scripts />
        <LiveReload />
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

If the data in your loader in extremely slow and you're unable to speed it up, you might want to show fallback UI such as a skeleton which can be done with [`defer`](https://remix.run/docs/en/v1/guides/streaming#using-defer).

```js
export function loader({ params }: LoaderArgs) {
  return defer({
    // NOTE: `getFoo` isn't awaited
    foo: getFoo()
  });
}

export default function Component() {
  const data = useLoaderData<typeof loader>();
  return (
    <main>
      <h1>Foo</h1>
      <Suspense fallback={<div>Skeleton UI...</div>}>
        <Await
          resolve={data.foo}
          errorElement={
            <div>Error loading foo</div>
          }
        >
          {(foo) => (
            <div>
              {JSON.stringify(foo, null, 2)}
            </div>
          )}
        </Await>
      </Suspense>
    </main>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to hold the answers:

```
import { useNavigation } from "@remix-run/react";

function SomeComponent() {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  navigation.state;
  navigation.location;
  navigation.formData;
  navigation.formAction;
  navigation.formMethod;
}
```

You appear to be able to hook into the navigation.state which changes from idle to loading when a link/NavLink has been clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @Richard, For someone who wants a readymade loader ui spinning icon.

```
const navigation = useNavigation();


{navigation.state !== "idle" ?
    <div className="absolute z-50 h-[calc(100%-5.5rem)] w-[calc(100%-15.5rem)] flex justify-center items-center bg-slate-300 opacity-60">
      <div
        className="inline-block h-20 w-20 animate-spin rounded-full border-8 border-solid border-current border-r-transparent align-[-0.125em] text-black motion-reduce:animate-[spin_1.5s_linear_infinite]"
        role="status">
        <span
          className="!absolute !-m-px !h-px !w-px !overflow-hidden !whitespace-nowrap !border-0 !p-0 ![clip:rect(0,0,0,0)]"
        >Loading...</span>
      </div></div> : null}
```